# Sanitizing RSS input in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sanitization

I'm pulling in the RSS feed from Craigslist into a rails app I'm building. When I try and insert content from the posts into my database, there's plenty of bad characters that cause the database to choke.

I've tried a few different methods (the Sanitize plugin, hpricot, regexing the input) but nothing seems to work right.

I'm still a rails noob so I thought I'd appeal to the community. Any tips on how to handle bum characters in RSS feeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials) ([Railscasts video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/190-screen-scraping-with-nokogiri))?

Actually Ryan Bates has a screen cast on feed parsing:  [feed parsing](http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing).

Answer (score 0):

I love Feed Normalizer http://feed-normalizer.rubyforge.org/